# Transform list of strings (indexes) to Numpy Array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have a list where every value is presented only one, and I have another list with the desired order of a tokenized numpy array.

For instance:

```
sorted_values = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
a = ['a', 'c', 'g']
b = ['e']
```

I want to convert a and b (in a efficient) to a numpy array like this:

```
at = [1,0,1,0,0,0,1]
bt = [0,0,0,0,1,0,0]
```

Is there any efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the fact that the first array is already sorted, we could employ [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) for efficiency -

```
at = np.zeros(len(sorted_values), dtype=int)
bt = at.copy()
at[np.searchsorted(sorted_values, a)] = 1
bt[np.searchsorted(sorted_values, b)] = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `np.in1d`:

```
np.in1d(sorted_values, a).astype(int)
#array([1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1])

np.in1d(sorted_values, b).astype(int)
#array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0])
```